# How to add additional claims to ClaimsPrincipal after ADFS authentication on MVC app

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, owin, adfs, adfs4.0

We have an MVC 5 web app that uses ADFS 4 authentication. I'm trying to find the **best place where** I can add additional claims into the ClaimsPrincipal, after authentication has been completed.

Are there any events I can access, like OnAuthenticated? How do I access this kind of event?

This is what I intend to use once I can access the event:

```
IOwinContext context = Request.GetOwinContext();

if (appRoles != null)
{
    ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity);

    foreach (var role in appRoles)
    {
        claimsIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role", role));
    }

    context.Authentication.AuthenticationResponseGrant = new AuthenticationResponseGrant
        (new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity), new AuthenticationProperties { IsPersistent = true });
}
```

**EDIT:**
This is what my `App_Data\Startup.Auth.cs` file looks like:

```
public partial class Startup
{
    private static string realm = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Wtrealm"];
    private static string adfsMetadata = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ADFSMetadata"];

    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            CookieManager = new SystemWebCookieManager()
        });

        app.UseWsFederationAuthentication(
            new WsFederationAuthenticationOptions
            {
                Wtrealm = realm,
                MetadataAddress = adfsMetadata
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: This project was created several years ago. Never had this need until couple of weeks ago. And it seems OWIN/Katana is no longer in the buzz. Maybe we need to switch over to another client side authentication library? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/community?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Answer (score 0):

I encountered similar problem and managed to find a way to add additional claims after ADFS login in my MVC 5 app. More info can be found on [msdn link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.claims.claimsauthenticationmanager?view=netframework-4.8).

Here is code from that link.
Firstly create the new ClaimsAuthenticationManager class and inside set additional claims:

```
class SimpleClaimsAuthenticatonManager : ClaimsAuthenticationManager
{
    public override ClaimsPrincipal Authenticate(string resourceName, ClaimsPrincipal incomingPrincipal)
    {
        if (incomingPrincipal != null && incomingPrincipal.Identity.IsAuthenticated == true)
        {
            ((ClaimsIdentity)incomingPrincipal.Identity).AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "User"));
        }
        return incomingPrincipal; 
    }
}
```

Afterwards specify this class in web.config file, under **identityConfiguration** element:

```
<system.identityModel>  
   <identityConfiguration>  
     <claimsAuthenticationManager type="ENTER YOUR NAMESPACE HERE.SimpleClaimsAuthenticatonManager, ENTER PROJECT NAME HERE" />  
     ...  
   </identityConfiguration>  
</system.identityModel>
```

Comment: Tried this but it didn't add the claim to the list of claims. At least it didn't show up in `@foreach (System.Security.Claims.Claim claim in System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Claims)` Also - I did not have `system.identityModel` in my web.config. It used to be in my older projects but VS did not add it in new project. So I simply added it manually.

Comment: Not sure about your logic for getting claims for the current user, never used it before. Here is what im using: 
var identity = (ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity;
IEnumerable<Claim> claims = identity.Claims;

Comment: `var identity = (ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity; IEnumerable<Claim> claims = identity.Claims;`  gives the same result. I'm guessing it has to do with how authentication is set up in my project. Did you see my edit?